# How does function() differ from function?

Tags: python, function

This is a function in my code-

```
class worker(Thread):
def run(self):
    for x in range(0,1100000000000):
        print (x)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Which gets called here-

```
def main():
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Start",command=worker.start)
```

Now Python also accepts this for the function assignment-

```
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Start",command=worker().start)
```

How are these two different?

Comment: In brief, in the first scenario the function is not called but stored, and then called later, when the button is pressed. In the second scenario the function is called immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first scenario waits for me to press the button before starting running the thread, while the second one starts running the thread as soon as the program is run. Can somebody explain what exactly is happening here.

Consider this piece of code:

```
ttk.Button(..., command=worker().start())
```

It behaves exactly the same as this:

```
w = worker()
result = w.start()
ttk.Button(..., command = result)
```

This is just how python works, and isn’t unique to tkinter. You are simply asking python to call a function, and you are passing the result as an argument to the `Button` constructor.

> So does it imply that every time there would be an update, a new thread instance

No, tkinter is single threaded, and `mainloop()` doesn’t re-execute your code. It simply listens to events and dispatches them to handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I started writing tkinter last week at work and found this very helpful tutorial

http://thinkingtkinter.sourceforge.net

Lessons 77, 78, and 79 are about this specific problem.

If you use "command = function" it stores the function and only calls it when the button is clicked or spacebar is pressed with the button focused.

However, if you use "command = function()" it calls that function when the button is created and doesn't work when you click the button.

Instead of "command = function()" use "command = lambda : function()"

More details are in lesson 78